# Same average function c++

Tags: c++

I'm trying to compare averages of an array and to detect if there is any similar averages,
for example if I have these averages 25,30,70,30,60 so the function should return true because 30 is twice there ,but it seems what I'm doing is wrong

```
bool sameAverage(Student Array[],int size)
{
    bool isSame=false;

    for (int i=0;i<size;i++)
    {
        for (int j=0;j<size;j++)
        {
            if (Array[i].getAverageGrade==Array[j].getAverageGrade)
                isSame=true;
        }

    }

    return isSame;
}
```

it is showing me a red line under the dot operator

Comment: Why do you believe it's wrong? You've given us no information to go off of.

Comment: it does not do what i want

Comment: @user3010026 What do you want?

Comment: And also, what does it do? How do you expect anyone to help if you don't give such basic info?

Comment: sorry I'll show you the whole code my bad I'm just a beginner here

Comment: @user3010026 If you think only this part is problematic that's OK, don't post more. But tell is what you expect and what you get.

Comment: @user3010026 You've asked 4 questions here and 3 of them have suffered from the same deficit of information. I love helping beginners, but it's a two-way street. If you continue failing to provide basic info, people are quickly going to stop bothering to answer your questions.

Comment: First, you iterate over the whole array twice, so at some point you will compare each student to himself. Second, you need to stop as soon as you have found a similarity. Third, comparing float numbers with `==` is normally a bad idea.

Comment: This question has nothing to do with Averages.

Comment: On a separate note, `getAverageGrade` has no `return` statement in it. This would not pass by any compiler without at least one warning. You shouldn't ask questions about code without at least fixing all of the compile warnings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Array[i].getAverageGrade` is a function. You can compare that function to another function (like `Array[j].getAverageGrade`) but what you really want is to

1. call that function
2. compare the result to the result of calling the other function:

   ```
   Array[i].getAverageGrade() == Array[j].getAverageGrade()
   ```

BTW: Please keep in mind what others have told you about comparing `double` values.

Comment: Thank you that was the problem in my program, it's good now!

Answer (score 0):

What I understand is that, you are looking for **duplicates in the array.**

First sort your array.

Then, Use a single loop to iterate through the array. Two loops are not needed.

```
bool sameAverage(Student Array[],int size)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < size - 1; i++) {
       //Use your favorite way to compare floating point numbers for equality 
       if ((Array[i].getAverageGrade() - Array[i + 1].getAverageGrade()) < 0.0001) {        
         return true;
       }
    }
    return false;
}
```